# Why does my graph sketching class draw sec, but not cosec or cot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, pygame

I have written a class for a graphical calculator in Pygame, which essentially just sketches a function. I've been working on a UI for it, but have discovered that it does not work for the reciprocal trigonometric functions cosec or cot (`1/(math.sin(x))` and `1/(math.tan(x))` in python respectively) although it does work for sec (`1/(math.cos(x))`).

I have been using the `lambda` keyword to input these functions into the class. For instance: `c = Curve(lambda x: x**2, (255, 0, 0))`

I am still working on improving it, it isn't in a finished form currently, and it most certainly isn't user proof yet at all. But, no matter what I try I cannot figure out why I cannot get cosec or cot to work with it.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
class Curve(object):
    def __init__(self, func, colour, width=1):
        self.function = func
        self.colour = colour
        self.width = width

    def render(self, colour=None, width=None):
        if self.function is None:
            return

        if colour is not None:
            self.colour = colour
        if width is not None:
            self.width = width

        try:
            self.function(0)
        except (NameError, TypeError,  AttributeError, ZeroDivisionError):
            return

        for x in range(0, WIDTH):
            try:
                fx = self.function((x / camera_pos[2]) + camera_pos[0])
                fx1 = self.function(((x + 1) / camera_pos[2]) + camera_pos[0])

            except (OverflowError, ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
                continue

            if type(fx) == complex or type(fx1) == complex:
                continue

            if 0 < transform_point(-fx, "y") < HEIGHT or 0 < transform_point(-fx1, "y") < HEIGHT:
                pygame.draw.line(SCREEN, self.colour, (x, transform_point(-fx, "y")),
                                 (x + 1, transform_point(-fx1, "y")), self.width)
```

The `transform_point()` function maps the cartesian coordinates onto the position on the screen.

```
camera_pos = [-400, -300, 1]  # [x, y, zoom]


def transform_point(value, axis):
    if str(axis).lower() == "x":
        return (value - camera_pos[0]) * camera_pos[2]

    elif str(axis).lower() == "y":
        return (value - camera_pos[1]) * camera_pos[2]
```

**EDIT:**

I have now found that the class works if you add any value to x in the function, even if that value is really small, such as: `cosec(x+0.0000000000001)`

I'm sorry for the image quality.

[image: Graphical Calculator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now been able to fix the issue, as it a result of how I was checking the validity of the input function with the clause:

```
try:
    self.function(0)
except (NameError, TypeError,  AttributeError, ZeroDivisionError):
    return
```

Here, I was making sure that the function was executable so that an error wouldn't occur when rendering the curve, by attempting to evaluate f(0). But as with cosec(x) and cot(x) f(0) is undefined, the class was making no attempt to render the curve. This explains why adding some amount to x, allows it to be drawn.

To remedy the issue I have changed the code to this, which deals with zero division errors separately.

```
try:
    self.function(0)
except (NameError, TypeError,  AttributeError):
    return
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
```